# Android Camera2 callback -- image appears to be cropped

Tags: java, android, f#, android-camera2

I'm working on the Camera2 API. This is work in progress, but I'm confused by image dimensions.

Here is how I've set up my callback (I'm working with Xamarin and the language is F#, but the specific language is not important):

```
type CameraCallback(surfaceView: SurfaceView) =
    inherit CameraDevice.StateCallback()
    interface ImageReader.IOnImageAvailableListener with
        member this.OnImageAvailable(imageReader) = 
            let image = imageReader.AcquireNextImage()
            let planes = image.GetPlanes()
            let yBuffer, uBuffer, vBuffer = planes.[0].Buffer, planes.[1].Buffer, planes.[2].Buffer
            image.Close()
    override this.OnOpened(cameraDevice) =
        let imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(surfaceView.Width, surfaceView.Height, ImageFormatType.Yuv420888, 1)
        imageReader.SetOnImageAvailableListener(this, null)
        let surfaces = [|surfaceView.Holder.Surface; imageReader.Surface|]
        cameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(surfaces, new CaptureSessionCallback(surfaces), null)
    override __.OnDisconnected(camera) = 
        camera |> ignore
    override __.OnError(camera, error) = 
        camera |> ignore
```

When I set up the `ImageReader`, the input dimensions of the surfaceView are 1440 (width) by 1801 (height). However, the `Image` object that is picked up by `OnImageAvailable` is 1440 x 1440.

There is clearly something I'm missing, but I'm having trouble finding out what it may be.

**ADDENDUM**: If I change the format from YUV 420 888 to JPEG, the correct dimensions come back. But in fact what I really need is to convert the image to an RGB byte array, and it seems that YUV is a preferable format. It is possible to request RGB as an image format type, but the device I'm testing on doesn't accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For YUV preview image, the callback returns the original landscape 1440x1800 image even is you set the preview surface to portrait. For still capture, in Jpeg, some devices perform true rotation of the image; others only mark the EXIF orientation flag.

In your code, you probably need

```
let imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(surfaceView.Height, surfaceView.Width, ImageFormatType.Yuv420888, 1)
```